# Error when trying to save file path to database

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, ms-access

I'm having an issue when I try to save a file path into Microsoft access DB, when I remove the image location from the below code, everything runs fine, as soon as I try to save a file path I get a syntax error...

below is the query...

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Company(companyName, phone, website, address, companyType, description, image) VALUES('" + 
            company.getName() + "','" + company.getPhone() + "','" +  company.getWebsite() + "','" +  
            company.getAddress() + "','" + company.getType() + "','" + company.getDescription() + "','" +
            company.getImage() + "')";
```

I know my code is open to sql injection but I will fix that at a later state, I have also tried parametrized queries to see if that would help the issue but it does not..

I've also tried replacing "\" with "/"

Any help would be appreciated as this is really annoying me...

Comment: Can you show us a sample of what company.getImage() returns?

Comment: What is the datatype for the image column? What is the exact error?

Comment: Datatype has been both short text and long text, and the it will normally return something like "Q:\Database\Profiles\ProfilePhotos\depp.jpg"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Image is a reserved word in MS-Access Database Engine. You cannot use it as is in a query like yours. You need to encapsulate it between square brackets (or better change that field name to avoid similar problems in future)

```
....., [Image]) VALUES (.....
```

If you are aware of the problems caused by string concatenations then I really suggest you to switch as soon as possible to a Parameterized Query. (For example, what do you think will happen if your company.getDescription returns a value containing single quote?)

Another important advice that I feel to give is to abandon the java-like  attitude to return properties of a class using get/set prefixed methods. One of the most distinguished feature of C# are properties. Use them.

```
public class Company
{
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public string Phone {get;set;}
    .... and so on...
}
```

Comment: .... Have to love it when you over think the easiest solution, thank you so much, will mark as answer when I can.

Comment: Oh, the amount of times I've had to "escape" column names in SQL when writing out scripts. Particularly the `Key` and `Value` ones... Good answer, Steve :)

Comment: If only I could +1 twice! Genuinely good to see SO members going the extra mile to look at things deeper than just the original question - by that, I mean the extra note about using properties.